# How to correctly position a header image with docx4j?

Tags: docx4j

I am trying to convert this Word document with a header showing an image on the right

http://www.filesnack.com/files/cduiejc7

to PDF using this sample code:

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutPDF.java

Here's the result:

http://www.filesnack.com/files/ctjs659h

While the Word document has the header image on the right, the converted PDF shows it on the left.

How can I make docx4j to reproduce the original document as PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is positioned relative to a paragraph:

```
      <w:drawing>
    <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251658240" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="791936E3" wp14:editId="575B92C8">
      <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
      <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
        <wp:posOffset>5317388</wp:posOffset>
      </wp:positionH>
      <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
        <wp:posOffset>-325755</wp:posOffset>
      </wp:positionV>
```

docx4j potential to support stuff like that in PDF output is limited by what XSL FO supports.  See docx4j's [TextBoxTest](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/test/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/XSLFO/TextBoxTest.java) class for what we can do with text boxes.

Currently, although we can position some textBoxes; we don't do the same for floating images: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/127

In the meantime, a possible workaround for some cases (eg float right) is to use a table.

Or possibly, you could try putting the image inside a text box!

Comment: Thank you! IMHO, in a perfect world docx4j should hide this hard-to-read-and-understand XSL FO stuff completely from the user. But alas... I've tried the "image inside textbox" approach. Although it looked promising I did not manage to get reliable results. However, I got what I want by using a table. Good old layout tables...